# Trace.axd shows ViewState Size Bytes even when the ViewStateMode="Disabled"

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, trace

I have a Asp.net page for which  ViewStateMode="Disabled". However when i pull up the trace.axd i still see a lot of viewstate for some of the controls. I am looking at the "ViewState Size Bytes (excluding children)" column in the Control Tree.

E.g. one such control being
ctl00$WMge$SLMP$ctl00$rptRows$ctl07$ctl02   System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl   4642    ***1824***    0

But when i look at the viewstate of the page it is pretty small and looks correct. Any idea what could be the reason for this big difference between the viewstate seen in the page source and that shown in Trace.axd?

Comment: Well,my question is I am seeing a big difference in the size of the data in the __Viewstate variable(1670 bytes) and that when i sum the bytes of individual controls shown in Trace.axd(13016 bytes). I am seeing that for individual controls(DataBoundLiteralControl in above case) trace.axd  shows me viewstate bytes which i feel might  not be a part of the viewstate. Confused what the "ViewState Size Bytes (excluding children)" in trace.axd really means.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to completely get rid of viewstate and the associated hidden fields that I've experienced is to use a hack in the codebehind. That hack is explained here.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-disable-or-remove-ViewState-Hidden-Field-in-ASP.Net-Page.aspx

Basically during the Page's Render you look for the hidden fields and remove them. I had to implement this awhile back when I was doing some jquery stuff that was pulling in a second aspx page and the view state from that page was mixing in with the one from the parent page and causing problems. The other way to avoid viewstate is to simply use MVC, but that's really not an option unless you're starting a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a Master and a content page.

**MASTER PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONTENT PAGE**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

</asp:Content>
```

This will show you below output in your rendered page.

[image]

You can use below code to avoid this situation.

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(hWriter);
        string html = sb.ToString();
        html = Regex.Replace(html, "<input[^>]*id=\"(__VIEWSTATE)\"[^>]*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        writer.Write(html);
    }
}
```

The code will modify the rendered HTML. Below is the final output
[image]

[**Reference**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-disable-or-remove-ViewState-Hidden-Field-in-ASP.Net-Page.aspx)